# Windows script to detect if Apache is not working and then restart

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, powershell

For development purposes, I'm running an Apache server on my windows machine.  Its very non-critical, but sometimes I'll be running processes that take a long time and Apache will stop server requests.  Restarting the Apache service works just fine when this happens.

Is there a script out there somewhere that can detect if Apache is failing to load pages and then restart the service if it is?

It would probably look something like this:

```
LOAD localhost/index.php
IF LOAD FAILED:
   RESTART APACHE SERVICE
```

Comment: " I'll be running processes that take a long time and Apache will stop server requests. " Is this with respect to Apache? Or are you referring to other external process which place highload on your machine, blocking Apache?

Comment: They place maybe a medium load on the machine.  Apache seems to be locking up periodically due to whatever is going on.  Sometimes it crashes, sometimes it just stops servicing requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it externally with WGet.exe and the scheduler service:

```
wget -o:foo http://localhost/page_of_interest.php || powershell.exe restart-service apache
```

Not sure which OS you're using, so YMMV with this task scheduler config:

Assume your batch script is called c:\bin\files\ca.cmd, type this at the command line:

```
schtasks.exe /create /u administrator /p password /sc minute /mo 2 /tn "Check Apache every 2 minutes" /tr c:\bin\files\ca.cmd
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much!  Do you know how I could set this command to run every minute or so?